# Kubuntu 22.10 installation keeps crashing!

Tags: crash, 22.10

when installing Linux Kubuntu, version 22.10, the installation aborts!
Only an error message is displayed, see picture attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9mcL.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL41H.jpg)

My question.
Where can I find the logdatein to the aborted installation?
So that I can get more information and also provide it here.

The specs of my machine:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte X570 AORUS ULTRA
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core
- GPU: nVidia [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER]
- RAM: G.Skill F4-3200C16_8GIS, DDR43200 XMP (2x8GB)
- SSD: Apacer AS2280P4 480GB M.2

Comment: Have you tried any other distros? What about installing Kubuntu 22.04, then upgrading to 22.10?

Comment: Yes, have also tried UbuntuMate 22.00, Kubuntu 22.04.
The same result.

Comment: OK, now try a non-Ubuntu distro so we can narrow this down.